# Apache Avro schema examples and documentation

Tags: avro

I'm trying to define a less-than-trivial Avro schema with little success; when it won't throw schema syntax errors it will not produce all the types I'm trying to define in the schema.

Is there a complete specification of the possible contents of an avsc definition? I keep guessing from what I understand from the Doc spec but evidently it's not enough.

Best,

Edoardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it...

According [this ML thread](http://apache-avro.679487.n3.nabble.com/Using-custom-defined-types-in-schemas-td2666914.html) protocols can define multiple cross-referencing object types. Keeping this cue in mind the documentation does appear to say that an avsc (schema) can only contain one type definition.